# ¿Cómo almacenar multiples archivos con WriteFile en Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, filewriter

Tengo el siguiente código que me crea un archivo de audio:

```
app.post('/audio', (req, res) =>{
        audio.synthesize(params, function(err, audio){
        if(err) console.log(err)
        else{
          fs.writeFile('./public/audio.mp3', audio, 'binary', err => {
              console.log("Listo");
            });
          }
        }
    });
```

Quiero que cada vez que se ejecute el metodo `POST` me pueda crear ese audio con diferentes nombres. Con este codigo solo me guarda 1 archivo llamado `audio.mp3`, y cada vez que se ejecuta sobreescribe ese archivo. Me gustaría que cada vez que se ejecuta, pueda crear, por ejemplo `audio1.mp3`, `audio2.mp3`.. etc

**¿Cómo podría arreglarlo?** !Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución de @gugadev es muy ingeniosa, yo te daré otra que también podrías aplicar.

Puedes capturar la fecha y hora en la que se ejecuta el método y se lo agregas al nombre del archivo, así siempre tendrás un archivo diferente y además con el nombre de archivo rápidamente ubicas los datos de fecha y hora en que fue creado el mismo.

Para lograr esto sólo debes capturar en una variable tipo Date la fecha y hora del sistema y luego puedes darle el formato que requieras.

Un ejemplo de cómo puedes anexar la fecha y hora al nombre del archivo sería la siguiente:

```js
const timestamp = new Date(Date.now());
const year = timestamp.getFullYear().toString();
const month = timestamp.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' + timestamp.getMonth().toString() : timestamp.getMonth().toString();
const day = timestamp.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + timestamp.getDate().toString() : timestamp.getDate().toString();
const hour = timestamp.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + timestamp.getHours().toString() : timestamp.getHours().toString();
const minutes = timestamp.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + timestamp.getMinutes().toString() : timestamp.getMinutes().toString();
const seconds = timestamp.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + timestamp.getSeconds().toString() : timestamp.getSeconds().toString();

const fileName = `audio-${year}${month}${day}${hour}${minutes}${seconds}.mp3`;

console.log(fileName);
```

Así tu implementación podría quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
app.post('/audio', async (req, res) => {
  const publicFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');

  audio.synthesize(params, (err, audio) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
    const timestamp = new Date(Date.now());
    const year = timestamp.getFullYear().toString();
    const month = timestamp.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' + timestamp.getMonth().toString() : timestamp.getMonth().toString();
    const day = timestamp.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + timestamp.getDate().toString() : timestamp.getDate().toString();
    const hour = timestamp.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + timestamp.getHours().toString() : timestamp.getHours().toString();
    const minutes = timestamp.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + timestamp.getMinutes().toString() : timestamp.getMinutes().toString();
    const seconds = timestamp.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + timestamp.getSeconds().toString() : timestamp.getSeconds().toString();

    const fileName = `audio-${year}${month}${day}${hour}${minutes}${seconds}.mp3`;

    fs.writeFile(`${publicFolder}/${fileName}`, audio, 'binary', (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
      }
      // ...
      // enviar respuesta
      // ...
    });
  }
});
```

Ahora ya tienes otra forma de generar nombres diferentes para los archivos.

Comment: muchas gracias! Estoy probando con los dos para ver cual me conviene más

Answer (score 2):

Obviamente llevando un contador de los audios. Puedes crear una función que lea el directorio y te devuelva el total de archivos:

```
export default async function getAudioCount(path: string): Promise<number|Error> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(path, (err: Error, files: string[]) => {
      if (err) { return reject(err) }
      resolve(files.length)
    })
  })
}
```

Al momento de guardar el archivo, le concatenas a *audio* el total de audios más una unidad, que representa al nuevo audio.

```
app.post('/audio', async (req, res) => {
  const publicFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
  const audioCount = await getAudioCount(publicFolder)

  audio.synthesize(params, function (err, audio) {
    if(err) { // siempre maneja el error
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message })
    } 

    fs.writeFile(`${publicFolder}/audio${audioCount+1}.mp3`, audio, 'binary', err => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message })
      }
      // enviar respuesta satisfactoria
    })
  }
})
```

Como consejo:

- Siempre usa `path.resolve` para obtener rutas absolutas de los directorios.
- Siempre retorna una respuesta al cliente.
- No uses `console.log` para manejar errores.

Comment: por qué me sale este error en la sintaxis? `'types' can only be used in a .ts file`

Comment: @IsaacAlejandro Ah, perdón, es que escribí el código en Typescript por la costumbre. Elimina todos los tipos (`: Error`, `: Promise<number | Error>`), etc.

Comment: @gugudev muchísimas gracias!